# Fade in/out animation cause the ScrollViewer's content blurry

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8

Here is my code, it can runs on Windows Phone 8 emulator.

- XAML:

  ```
  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
      <ScrollViewer>
          <StackPanel>
              <Button Content="Sample Content" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                  <Button.Style>
                      <Style TargetType="Button">
                          <Setter Property="Width" Value="400"></Setter>
                          <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"></Setter>
                          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                          <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                          <Setter Property="Template">
                              <Setter.Value>
                                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                      <Grid>
                                          <Border CornerRadius="10,10,10,10"
                                                  Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                                                  BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
                                                  x:Name="border" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                              <Border.RenderTransform>
                                                  <TransformGroup>
                                                      <ScaleTransform />
                                                      <SkewTransform />
                                                      <RotateTransform />
                                                      <TranslateTransform />
                                                  </TransformGroup>
                                              </Border.RenderTransform>
                                              <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                          </Border>
                                      </Grid>
                                  </ControlTemplate>
                              </Setter.Value>
                          </Setter>
                      </Style>
                  </Button.Style>
              </Button>
              <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                  Lorem ipsum Pariatur sint occaecat sunt sint do labore adipisicing 
                  eiusmod incididunt culpa laborum consequat magna dolor labore sunt sed 
                  ullamco anim adipisicing do pariatur ea esse qui sint magna in voluptate 
                  Duis id ut anim id.
              </TextBlock>
          </StackPanel>
      </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
  ```
- C#:

  ```
  private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      var storyb = new Storyboard();
      Duration Show_Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 450));
      DoubleAnimation m_OpacityAni = new DoubleAnimation();
      m_OpacityAni.Duration = Show_Duration;
      m_OpacityAni.From = 1.0;
      m_OpacityAni.To = 0.0;
      m_OpacityAni.AutoReverse = true;

      storyb.Children.Add(m_OpacityAni);

      Storyboard.SetTarget(m_OpacityAni, ContentPanel);
      Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(m_OpacityAni, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.Opacity)"));

      storyb.Begin();
  }
  ```

Right now, because the height of content is smaller than the Grid named "ContentPanel", so when the animation begins, all contents will fade in/out without blurriness. But if I duplicate that TextBlock in order to make the ScrollViewer longer(make it scrollable), then run the animation again. Those contents will display blurry until it ends.

If I remove the ScrollViewer tag, all contents will display clear.

Although it won't cause some bad side effects, but I wanna know why it will display like this.

Look forward to your answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it sets `ScrollViewer.CacheMode = CacheMode.BitmapCache` during the animation.

Comment: Maybe when I use animation on this control, it use BitmapCache inside. So it looks blurry.